# PCap performance

Tags: c#, c++, performance, pcap

Which c-sharp wrapper of Pcap is fastest?
How fast is PCap compared to using sockets?

Comment: How would you use sockets in a comparable way?

Comment: You have a piece of info, you either send it via socket using winsock or send it directly to link layer by passing OS using winPCap.

In both cases I am sending information from my side to a specific destination. Theoretically winPCap sound faster but I am just wondering if implementation or something else causes overhead that offsets the gains of bypassing OS.

Comment: @Jon: It is comparable with raw sockets, if he's just going to use pcap to capture and filter out irrelevant packages. I think his efficiency concerns are about the overhead in pcap's filtering mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com) is faster than other wrappers since it uses C++/CLI wrapping instead of PInvoke.

In general I've never encountered performance issues with WinPcap (it also depends how you use it).

Comment: If I may ask, what do you use pcap for? is it network sniffing on data exchange between user applications? How do you find pcap performance compared with regular socket usage?

Comment: I use WinPcap for general packet sniffing. I haven't compared WinPcap with regular socket usage, but I'm not sure how you can sniff packets that aren't intended for the computer by using regular sockets.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually planning to use it for regular application data transfer which I am currently doing over socket with the hope of getting lower latency, but what I have read so far, it is only appropriate for packet sniffing.

Answer (score 1):

[SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page) is appropriate both for capture (sniffing) and transmission (similar to UdpClient and TcpClient). I've used it in an application for high-performance UDP transmission and it could be tweaked to be significantly faster than UdpClient (there are examples of high-perf sending in the source).

Comment: [c#]Yes, why the downvote indeed? As the author of SharpPcap the library has gone from being fast to being much much faster in the 4.0 release, as a result of some excellent work by a contributor. The current packet processing rates are VERY high. We have a built in set of performance tests. For details about how much faster you can look at the git log for the project on sourceforge. I made sure to include them with each performance improving commit for documentation. I'm the author of SharpPcap btw.